# How to include concatenation in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate-criteria

I am trying to migrate from native mysql query into hibernate but i am wondering how can i do this following query into hibernate? This is my code:

```
 sql = "SELECT s.* FROM student s WHERE concat_ws(', ',s.last_name,concat_ws(' ',concat_ws(' ',s.first_name,s.suffix),s.middle_name)) like ?"
 pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
 pstmt.setString(1, fullName);
 ...
```

My point here is the concatenation of my fields: **last_name, first_name, suffix, and middle_name**. I used **concat_ws** so to ignore the **NULL** value from one of my field.

**EDIT**

So I try my code something like this:

```
String sql = "SELECT s.* FROM student s WHERE concat_ws(', ',s.last_name,concat_ws(' ',concat_ws(' ',s.first_name,s.suffix),s.middle_name)) like :name";
SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
query.addEntity(Student.class);
query.setParameter("name", fullName);
student = (Student) query.list().get(0);
```

but why it gives me null?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert MySQL query into HQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768907/how-to-convert-mysql-query-into-hql-query)

Comment: It seems this question has nothing to do with "swing". If so, please remove that tag.

Comment: Oh sorry. Indeed.

Answer (score 1):

JPQL provides a function named CONCAT...

Comment: At first sight, this seems a likely candidate (although you could enrich your answer, possibly to note that CONCAT allows variable number of arguments, which makes for a more readable version). Nonetheless, see the OP's comment, he relies on special handling of null values through concat_ws. Does concat also do that ?